# How to execute a processor only when another processor is not executing?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am inserting/updating data into a table. The database system does not provide an "Upsert" functionality. Thus I am using a staging table for the insert followed by a merge into the "final" table and finally I am truncating the staging table.

This leads to a race condition. If new data is inserted into the staging table between the merge+truncate this data is lost.

How can I make sure this does not happen?

I have tried to model this via Wait/Notify, but this is not a clean solution either. The queue for the "Put Data into staging table" PutDatabaseRecord processor could be filled and "MergeVertica for Insert/Update" ExecuteSQL could still execute.

[image: Nifi Flow]

Comment: just an idea: add `processed` column to stage table. insert with value 0. and in merge use: `update stage set processed=1; merge where processed=1; delete where processed=1;` or you could add more statuses... so: use power of database to manage state of data in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a **MonitorActivity** processor with a 60 or 30 sec threshold and use the Inactive output with a **Continually Send Messages** set to "false".

Have the success of the SQL inserts into staging connection into your **MonitorActivity**, this way if no activity is seen in the last X seconds he will trigger a flowfile that will start your Merge Process.

Download the template from https://codeshare.io/aJNNkn

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have not heard of "MonitorActivity" before.
There is still the case, where a flowfile is "stuck" in some upstream processor and just as we start the merge it gets transferred to the PutDatabaseRecord processor. Could this happen, if e.g. CPU is busy?