# NiFi Create Indexes after Inserting Records into table

Tags: apache-nifi

I've got my first Process Group that drops indexes in table.
Then that routes to another process group the does inserts into table. 
After successfully inserting the half million rows, I want to create the indexes on the table and analyze it.  This is typical Data Warehouse methodology.  Can anyone please give advice on how to do this?

I've tried setting counters, but cannot reference counters in Expression Language.  I've tried RouteOnAttribute but getting nowhere.  Now I'm digging into Wait & Notify Processors - maybe there's a solution there??

I have gotten Counters to count the flow file sql insert statements, but cannot reference the Counter values via Expression Language.  Ie this always returns nulls:  "${InsertCounter}"  where InsertCounter is being set properly it appears via my UpdateCounter process in my flow.

So maybe this code can be used?

In the wait processor set the Target Signal Count to ${fragment.count}.

Set the Release Signal Identifier in both the notify and wait processor to ${fragment.identifier}

nothing works

Comment: FYI, my first Process Group works fine - it truncates the table and drops indexes just fine.  The 2nd Process Group then Inserts the records just fine into the table.  I'm having trouble with the 3rd Process Group.  It needs to run once.  The 2nd Process Group  has a flow of half million sql inserts in its flow.  I just want to re-create the indexes & Analyze the table only once, after the 2nd process group doing all the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wait/Notify processors to do that.
I assume you're using ExecuteSQL, SplitAvro? If so, the flow will look like:

## Split approach

At the 2nd ProcessGroup

- ExecuteSQL: e.g. 1 output FlowFile containing 5,000 records
- SpritAvro: creates 5,000 FlowFiles, this processor adds `fragment.identifier` and `fragment.count` (=5,000) attributes.

  - split:

    - XXXX: Do some conversion per record
    - PutSQL: Insert records individually
    - Notify: Increase count for the `fragment.identifier` (Release Signal Identifier) by 1. Executed 5,000 times.
  - original - to the next ProcessGroup

At the 3rd ProcessGroup

- Wait: waiting for `fragment.identifier` (Release Signal Identifier) to reach `fragment.count` (Target Signal Count). This route processes the `original` FlowFile, so executed only once.
- PutSQL: Execute a query to create indices and analyze tables

Alternatively, if possible, using Record aware processors would make the flow simpler and more efficient.

## Record approach

- ExecuteSQL: e.g. 1 output FlowFile containing 5,000 records
- Perform record level conversion: With UpdateRecord or LookupRecord, you can do data processing without splitting records into multiple FlowFiles.
- PutSQL: Execute a query to create indices and analyze tables. Since the single FlowFile containing all records, no Wait/Notify is required, the output FlowFile can be connected to the downstream flow.

Comment: Here is an example NiFi flow template using Wait/Notify with the Split approach described above.
https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/20125d663d2116c6dae1eecae8d7acbc

Answer (score 0):

I Think my suggestion to this question will fit into your scenario as well

[How to execute a processor only when another processor is not executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479331/how-to-execute-a-processor-only-when-another-processor-is-not-executing)

Check it out